# How do I group pairs of List<double> in a List<List<double>>

Tags: c#

I have 6 lists.

```
List<double> listdSignal0X = new List<double>();
List<double> listdSignal0Y = new List<double>();
List<double> listdSignal1X = new List<double>();
List<double> listdSignal1Y = new List<double>();
List<double> listdSignal2X = new List<double>();
List<double> listdSignal2Y = new List<double>();
```

I want to group them in XY pairs in a List<List>.

```
List<List<double>> listlistdXYSignals = new List<List<double>>();
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal0X);
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal0Y);
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal1X);
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal1Y);
etc.
```

This does not group them in pairs. I want

```
listlistdXYSignals[0] ... to retrieve both ... listdSignal0X ... and ... listdSignal0Y
listlistdXYSignals[1] ... to retrieve both ... listdSignal1X ... and ... listdSignal1Y
etc.
```

The pairs of XY lists are the same length.  Each pair of XY lists could be different lengths.  Signal1X and Signal1Y are the same length (1000 values).  Signal1X is a different length than Signal2X (200 values).

These pairs of XY lists are passed to a function that creates multiple plots on a WPF xaml.

I have tried:

```
List<Tuple<List<double>, List<double>>> listtupledSignals = new List<Tuple<List<double>, List<double>>>();
listtupledSignals.Add(listdSignalX, listdSignalY);
```

Error message, "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments".

How do I group pairs of

```
List<double>
```

in a

```
List<List<double>>
```

?

```
List<List<double>, List<double>>
```

does not work either.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example for us to help you? Also you're missing a `()` at the end of `List<List<double>> listlistdXYSignals = new List<List<double>>;`, maybe a type-o?

Comment: This data structure doesn't make a lot of since yet. Can you simplify all this into just a Dictionary?

Comment: @gunr2171 I agree, the post is lacking context.

Comment: Why do you have 6 lists? What are you trying to do with them? Are you required to have them or can another data structure be used instead?

Comment: I think this all needs to be rethought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works to create:

```
List<Point> listPointsTop = new List<Point>();
List<Point> listPointsMiddle = new List<Point>();
List<Point> listPointsBottom = new List<Point>();
```

then

```
CreateXYPoints(listdSignal0X, listdSignal0Y, ref listPointsTop);
CreateXYPoints(listdSignal1X, listdSignal1Y, ref listPointsMiddle);
CreateXYPoints(listdSignal2X, listdSignal2Y, ref listPointsBottom);
 
private void CreateXYPoints(List<double> listdSignalX, List<double> listdSignalY, ref List<Point> listPoints)
{
  int iNumOfPoints = listdSignalX.Count;
  for (int ii = 0; ii < iNumOfPoints; ii++) {
    double dX = listdSignalX[ii];
    double dY = listdSignalY[ii];
    Point pt = new Point(dX, dY);
    listPoints.Add(pt);
  };
}//CreateXYPoints
```

Then use:

```
List<List<Point>> listlistpoxySignals = new List<List<Point>>();
listlistpoxySignals.Add(listPointsTop);
listlistpoxySignals.Add(listPointsMiddle);
listlistpoxySignals.Add(listPointsBottom);
```

listlistpoxySignals is passed to the plot xaml function.

```
listlistpoxySignals[0] contains contents of listdSignal0X, listdSignal0Y 
listlistpoxySignals[1] contains contents of listdSignal1X, listdSignal1Y 
listlistpoxySignals[2] contains contents of listdSignal2X, listdSignal2Y.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the size of the lists are equal.

```cs
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}

var listdSignal0Y = new List<double>(new []
{
    1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9
});
var listdSignal0X = new List<double>( new []
{
    2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9
});
var listdSignal2X = new List<double>(new []
{
    3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9
});
var listdSignal2Y = new List<double>(new []
{
    4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9
});
var listdSignal1X = new List<double>(new []
{
    5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9
});
var listdSignal1Y = new List<double>(new []
{
    6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9
});

var listdXYSignals = new List<Point>();
            
if (listdSignal0X.Count == listdSignal0Y.Count)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < listdSignal0X.Count; i++)
    {
        listdXYSignals.Add(
            new Point
            {
                X = listdSignal0X[i],
                Y = listdSignal0Y[i]
            });
    }
}

foreach (var o in listdXYSignals)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"X: {o.X} - Y: {o.Y}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to hold the pair of lists:

```
class SignalListPair
{
    public List<double> X { get; set; } = new List<double>();
    public List<double> Y { get; set; } = new List<double>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var signal0XY = new SignalListPair();
   var signal1XY = new SignalListPair();
   var signal2XY = new SignalListPair();
   var signals = new List<SignalListPair>();
   signals.Add(signal0XY);
   signals.Add(signal1XY);
   signals.Add(signal2XY);

   var x0 = signals[0].X;
   var y0 = signals[0].Y;
   var x1 = signals[1].X;
   var y1 = signals[1].Y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using tuples; they are a very clean solution to your problem

```cs
var listOfXYPairs = new List<(double, double)>();
listOfXYPairs.Add((listdSignal0X, listdSignal0Y)); // remember about the ((x, y)), a tuple (x, y) is a single argument
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try zipping them up using LINQ if they are of equal length.

```
List<List<(double,double)>> listlistdXYSignals = new List<List<(double,double)>>();
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal0X.Zip(listdSignal0Y).ToList());
listlistdXYSignals.Add(listdSignal1X.Zip(listdSignal1Y).ToList());
etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

I think what you need is a `List<Tuple<List<double>, List<double>>>`

Ref.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples

Comment: A list of tuples of list-pairs.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said, it's madness and doesn't answer the question